# How to implement `class NumericalAntiderivative`

Tags: c++11, numerical-integration

I seek to create a `class NumericalAntiderivative` that can be used like this:

```
auto f = [](double x){
    return std::sin(x); // in general this may be a complicated expression that is not analytically integrable
};
NumericalAntiderivative ad(f,minXofInterest,maxXofInterest);
// the line above may be costly, but the line below should be efficient
std::cout << "Integral of f from 0 to 5 is " << (ad(5.0)-ad(0.0)) << std::endl;
```

I have described some ideas in [this maths question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2755123/86969), but the question may be more suitable for SO. I just need some ideas/pointers that may lead to a good way to accomplish this objective.

Comment: do you need to implement this yourself? there are plenty of libraries that will do it for you.

Comment: Do you need a numeric integral?

Comment: @Chris I don't know of a library that does what I need. Solutions that integrate to specific bounds are commonplace, but note the comment (5th line) in my code. I will call `ad(...)` millions of times, so I prefer to pre-calculate as much as possible during construction.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I'm not sure I understand your question. I need to evaluate the antiderivative of an arbitrary function at many different points on its domain.

Comment: Well libraries like ginac (C++ though) give you often analytic integrals. Arbitrary function is fine unless you don't know the functions / class of functions in question. In which case, I'd look at numeric integrators like CVODE etc.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Thanks for the references, but the symbolic approach will only work in very special cases, and the standard numeric approach is geared to evaluating a single definite integral on a single interval. I would like to reuse computations (carried out in the constructor) on different intervals overlapping each other.

Comment: Symbolic often doesn't in real life problems. But what you are describing  can at least be done with boost::numeric::odeint. Here's the thing. I don't know your background, but oftentimes folks don't know, what modern integrators can do in magic like adaptive step sizing etc, which can reduce computation time by orders of magnitude

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Still, I would be surprised if stepping from zero each time could rival stepping from a nearby pre-calculated point, for example, which can be picked from a pre-calculated array.